# Div resizing with mouse expands too fast

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

For fun, I am creating a widget that can be toggled to use vertical typing (e.g. for Japanese). The vertical part is being done with a div that is `contenteditable`. At the moment, you can see both the textarea and the div, and watch their content change in sync. The checkbox does nothing yet.

My problem is that the `svg` that is the "handle" to drag and resize was inside the editable div, and this would get messed up if the user cut from or pasted into the div. So that's the real problem I'm solving, and if there's a better fix, let me know. In an attempt to fix this, I am putting the editable div within another div that has the svg, in order that the internal editable div will not affect it.

After doing this, the resize functionality does not work correctly. After clicking down on the handle, the div resizes extremely fast downwards (it's height growing).

[image]

Here is what I was trying to do "working": https://jsfiddle.net/m4Ljuzyn/167/

And here is the one where the resize is broken after I changed the layout a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/m4Ljuzyn/190/

I am using pure JavaScript only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` are relative to the element's parent. You're using that relative value with the mouse event's `clientX/Y` value and it's producing undesired results.

Take advantage of `getBoundingClientRect` for proper coordinates in your `mousemove` handler.

```
var bounds = verticalTextarea.getBoundingClientRect();

verticalTextarea.style.width = (evt.clientX - bounds.left) + "px";
verticalTextarea.style.height = (evt.clientY - bounds.top) + "px";
```

Be warned: `getBoundingClientRect` is an expensive calculation, and may negatively affect performance.

**Update: Added Forked JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/csoh7xzv/

Comment: Thanks! It must've only been working before because the parent was the outermost div.

Comment: what is it with that checkbox?? Correct that it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @mathheadinclouds This was made to be a single textarea where you toggle the vertical/horizontal with the checkbox. For debug purposes, I show them both. In the end, I ditched my custom textarea, because I found a CSS property that controls text direction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation